# Setting up TextStyle with initialization cells in Mathematica 6+

Tags: notebooks, formatting, options, version-6

It used to be quite straightforward to change the default settings of a notebook in terms of inputs, outputs, text styles and font sizes in previous versions of *Mathematica* using initialization cells with commands such as [`$TextStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24TextStyle.html) and [`$FormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24FormatType.html).

However, as of *Mathematica* version 6, functions have been superseded by [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BaseStyle.html).
May I know how to use this new function to accomplish the same?

Comment: user656570 - Could you configure your account properly so that you have a real user name?

Comment: See [v5_2/functions/$TextStyle](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/$TextStyle) for the old documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `SetOptions[Graphics, BaseStyle -> {...}]`.  For example

```
SetOptions[Graphics, BaseStyle -> {Large, Red, FontFamily -> "Times", Italic}];
Graphics[{Circle[], Text["test"]}]
```

[image: example1]

Note that the `Text` inherits its `BaseStyle` from the surrounding `Graphics`.
The `Text` function also takes a `BaseStyle` option, but for some reason it doesn't seem to do anything (in Mma v8.0.4) - this might be a bug. For example:

```
SetOptions[Text, BaseStyle -> {Large, "Color" -> Green}]
{Text["test"], Text["test"]//Graphics}
```

[image: example2]

However explicit `BaseStyle` options passed to `Text` do work:

```
Graphics[{Circle[], Text["test", BaseStyle -> {Large, "Color" -> Green}]}]
```

[image: example3]

Comment: Possibly related question: [How can I work out which functions work with SetOptions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/332/34)