# How can I work out which functions work with SetOptions?

Tags: options

Not all functions seem to work with `SetOptions`. e.g.

```
SetOptions[Grid, BaseStyle -> Directive[Red]];
Grid[{{"hello", "world"}}]

hello world
```

the font *is not* red.

```
SetOptions[Row, BaseStyle -> Directive[Red]];
Row[{"hello", "world"}]

hello world
```

...and the font *is* red.

[image]

```
SetOptions[InputField, FieldSize -> 5];
InputField[Dynamic[x]]
```

the input field size is *much* larger than 5. But on the other hand

```
InputField[Dynamic[x], Sequence @@ Options[InputField]]
```

yields an input field with field size 5.

[image]

...and so on.

What is the easiest way to work out (i.e. make a list of ...) which functions can't be used with `SetOptions`?

Comment: It'd also be interesting to know which *objects* work with it, e.g. it works with `Graph`, `$FrontEndSession`, etc. but all these are somewhat special

Comment: Really good question! +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted in the question, when you set an option to a function which appears not to work with `SetOptions` the options **do** get set, e.g. from the question:

```
InputField[Dynamic[x], Sequence @@ Options[InputField]]
```

but for whatever reason the global setting does not get used locally by default.

Another interesting case is this:

```
SetOptions[Grid, Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]
```

which returns a list of `Grid` options with the new `Background`, yet when you do the same with `GridBox`

```
SetOptions[GridBox, Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]
SetOptions::nspt: "SetOptions of GridBox is not supported"
```

So testing the actual "box form" seems to highlight the problem. In this case `GridBox` is not supported for `SetOptions` even though `Grid` did not return an error. So the following solution is a variation of what was provided to me by tech support. `Check` can be used to return something in the case of a `SetOptions` error:

```
Check[SetOptions[GridBox, "a" -> "b"], err, SetOptions::nspt]

SetOptions::nspt: "SetOptions of GridBox is not supported."
err
```

First get a list of names:

```
names = Names["System`*"]
```

test the names for the `SetOptions` error

```
list = Quiet[Map[Check[SetOptions[ToExpression[#], "a" -> "b"]; Null, #, 
      SetOptions::nspt] &, names]];
```

delete the `Null` elements

```
DeleteCases[list, Null]

{ActionMenuBox,AnimatorBox,CheckboxBox,ColorSetterBox,CounterBox,DynamicBox,
DynamicModuleBox,DynamicWrapperBox,GridBox,InputFieldBox,ItemBox,Line3DBox,LineBox,
LocatorBox,LocatorPaneBox,OpenerBox,OptionValueBox,OverlayBox,PaneBox,PanelBox,
PaneSelectorBox,Point3DBox,PointBox,PopupMenuBox,ProgressIndicatorBox,RadioButtonBox,
RectangleBox,RotationBox,SetterBox,Slider2DBox,SliderBox,TabViewBox,TemplateBox,
TogglerBox,TooltipBox,ValueBox}
```

So we have a list of 36 types of boxes that cannot be used with `SetOptions`.

Comment: Despite new answers bumping questions to the top I missed this until now. +1  (Also, consider accepting your own answer.)

Comment: 95% of this answer came from tech support. Nevertheless it does seem to be the best way of finding this information so I am accepting "my own" answer.

Comment: re "is accepting your own answer good etiquette?" if you want the consensus opinion of this specific community I suggest a question in Meta; mine is that is that it is perfectly fine if it is a proper answer and not simply something of the form: "I ended up using Joe's answer with this small tweak:" which I am sure you have seen before.  In the case of an answer like this one could argue that it is *bad etiquette* to not accept your answer as then it doesn't show the problem as solved.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and Mike Honeychurch: I've checked that this method miss `Style`(StyleBox) and `Text`(InterpretationBox). What lead me to the doubts if this is the core of the problem. For example: `SetOptions[Style, FontColor -> Red]; Style["test"]` will not work while you can `SetOptions` on `StyleBox`. It is getting weirder, try to set `SetOptions[StyleBox, FontColor -> Red]` (set it to Automatic to undo) and later `SetOptions[StyleBox, FontSize -> 25]` <- it seems that color was changed on all types of cells while size only for "InlineText", but basic "InlineText" cell have no `StyleBox`...

Comment: @Kuba Also, function calling `GridBox` internally isn't necessarily influenced, for example: `SetOptions[MatrixForm, TableSpacing -> {5, 2}]; {#, # // ToBoxes} &@MatrixForm[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}]`.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know the direct answer to the specific question on `SetOptions`, but if we look at the *purpose* of (re)setting options globally, I have some alternative suggestion. A need to set options globally means that you need some persistent configuration of options which you'd like to be applied many times, without extra effort on your side. This can be achieved by creating such option(s) configuration and then always passing options locally (explicitly). It is possible to create helper functions / macros, which would automate this process for you and make it *look and feel* (almost) as if you have set your options globally.

I have implemented a simplistic [options configuration manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192599/create-functions-to-flexibly-define-chart-options-lists-in-mathematica/7197903#7197903), and a lexically scoped construct `withOptionConfiguration`, which can be wrapped around your code containing a function call of interest. One can also implement dynamically-scoped environments, for which the option-passing will happen also for all code called from the code within a construct. To my mind, this will save a lot of hassle even if / when you get the exhaustive answer to your direct question, since with the approach I suggest, you don't have at all to remember which functions work with `SetOptions` and which don't.

Comment: In a rare turn of events I shall not vote for your answer as I don't believe it addresses the question asked. (but I'll go find another answer of yours I haven't seen yet and vote for that to compensate)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I wanted to make this a comment, but it was too large for that. I actually strongly dislike resetting options globally (`SetOptions`), particularly for system functions, but also generally. I think this practice should be officially discouraged, since it changes the global state of the system. As soon as their will be many interdependent third-party applications / packages in widespread use, (and I hope this will happen, for the sake of Mathematica community), the use of `SetOptions` will create nothing but problems. My personal view, of course.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are right that this does not address the direct question, but I clearly stated so, and also I think it addresses the reason for this question. If I get lots of negative feedback on this from others, I may delete this answer and just incorporate this in the book.

Comment: Please do not delete it; again I know (or at least presume) that you cannot see my votes, but I still feel the need to explain why I don't vote for an otherwise thoughtful answer.  I do not share your blanket distaste for global options, because *Mathematica* is often an individually used and individualized software.  I would however be concerned by packages that changed my options without notice!

Comment: @LeonidShifrin No, please don't delete. An answer is always useful if it adds anything of substance to solving/understanding the question. Sometimes (generally, not specific to this), such answers can also be helpful in figuring out the underlying problem or if it's a conceptual misunderstanding on the OP's part. Deleting should be reserved for answers that talk of football when the question is on tennis. I can understand people not wanting to vote, but that doesn't diminish the usefulness.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You don't have to explain your voting, but I appreciate that you did - thanks! Now, "because Mathematica is often an individually used and individualized software. I would however be concerned by packages that changed my options without notice!" - but don't you see that there is no clear border between the two, as soon as people start really using each other's packages? A person A creates a useful package a.m and resets options of say Grid, and a.m crucially depends on that. A person B creates b.m and resets options of `Grid` differently. A person C wants to use a.m and b.m ...

Comment: @R.M. Well, thanks, that makes sense. Will let it live then :)

Comment: I think we are using global options differently.  If they are for a custom function, sure, why not use them for required functionality.  But for a system function I think it is Bad Form to mess with global options as part of a package, as I feel they are there for customization of the system.  If I set all my FontSize options to huge because of eyesight, I want that setting to persist without having to use custom wrappers, and if someone's package changes that setting I am going to get upset.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think you missed my point. For an (user)-extensible system, there should be virtually no difference between system functions and those provided by users. This is the key to success, as long as the development done by a community is concerned. And if you look at the package-writing guidelines, one of the main ones is "make your function behave as much like a built-in as possible". So, ideally, there is no difference. The same customization of the system can be made with locally-passed options, with a mechansim I specified, but in a *much* safer way. I never use `SetOptions` myself.

Comment: Chat please, if you have time: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2266/leonid-mr-wizard

Comment: Although this answer doesn't address the question it references a useful approach to dealing with options so I don't think it should be deleted. On the debate about the use of `SetOptions` I am with Mr Wizard. As an example, for my system, not used by any other person, I have `Joined->True` for `DateListPlot` in my init.m because there have never been cases where I personally wanted to see a plot with `Joined->False`.

Comment: @Mike I think, the whole fact that global options settings do not work *even for some built-in functions* (which I think can be qualiied as a bug) shows the fragility of the approach based on global options settings (note that `SetOptions` *does* work, in the sense that options really get reset. They are just not used!). I agree with you and Mr.Wizard when I look at it  from the end-user's viewpoint, but my post was from the developer's viewpoint, and I think most expert users who write packages would be better off using developer's viewpoint most of the time. My two cents.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason for this is that many functions pass their options to other functions that they call during evaluation. See for example [this answer to a related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618365/758485). So you can't set the option for the function you use, only the function that the option is passed to.

So for example, in one of my packages (you can guess which one, I have of course changed the initials of my employer to "XYZ") I have a function that starts with the definition:

```
XYZLineGraph[data:{{__?NumericQ} ..}, 
dates_List, opts:OptionsPattern[{XYZLineGraph, 
 DateListPlot, XYZDateTicks, XYZTickGrid, GraphNotesGrid}]] := (* more here *)
```

I cannot set the defaults for `XYZLineGraph` that are actually defaults of `DateListPlot` using `SetOptions[XYZLineGraph]`.

An example:

```
test = FinancialData["AAPL", {2008}];
SetOptions[XYZLineGraph, BaseStyle -> Directive[Red]];
XYZLineGraph[test]  (* not red *)
```

[image]

```
SetOptions[DateListPlot, BaseStyle -> Directive[Red]];
XYZLineGraph[test]
```

(* still not red, because I set the relevant defaults separately *)

```
DateListPlot[test]  (* is red *)
```

[image]

As for identifying which functions can have `SetOptions` work this way, I suspect the only way you could do this for built-in functions would be a laborious use of `Trace`.

Comment: hmmm, I might email you about that @Verbeia.

Comment: Don't tell me this question is about your implementation of the same functionality? That *is* funny.

Comment: No completely unrelated actually but given your answer I thought I would chat to you about it. I am the only person that uses my computer and I like to set certain configurations for functions I use regularly.

Comment: As you've shown, the issue is that `BaseStyle` is not an option of `XYZLineGraph`. However, you can make it one by including `Options[DateListPlot]` in the options for `XYZLineGraph`, using `FilterRules` to strip out any changes to the defaults you make. Then, using `FilterRules`, you pass the `DateListPlot` options to it from within `XYZLineGraph`.

Answer (score 1):

I expanded upon Mike Honeychurch's excellent solution by generalizing his solution into a general-purpose "Option Dictionary" creator.  It includes his use of `Check` to indicate whether you are allowed to use a `SetOptions` on a given symbol, but it also includes a formatted list of all the available options, not cluttered with the current default values.

The net output is formatted in a `Grid`-friendly manner, but need not be used with a `Grid`.  For example, you can use the raw `List` output with no arguments to generate an option dictionary for all of Mathematica, then do things like use `Cases` or `Position` to search for some particular "child option" that exists in any symbol in Mathematica.

Here is the code:

```
(* HoldComplete needed -- TemplateSequence options "DefaultValue" and "Delimiters" contain Sequence[] *)

FreeRulesQ = 
  Function[expr, FreeQ[Unevaluated@expr, _Rule | _RuleDelayed], 
   HoldAllComplete];

RulesToOptionList[rules_List] := Replace[
  Replace[
   ReplaceAll[
    rules,
    {Rule[opt_, val_?(FreeRulesQ)] :> opt, 
     RuleDelayed[opt_, val_?(FreeRulesQ)] :> opt}
    ],
   {Rule[opt_, val_] | RuleDelayed[opt_, val_] :> {opt, val}},
   {1, Infinity}
   ],
  opt : Except[_List] :> {opt, {}},
  {1}
  ]

SetOptionsQ = 
  Function[symbol, 
   Quiet@Check[SetOptions[ReleaseHold@symbol, {}]; True, False], 
   Listable];

With[{symbolListDefault = MakeExpression@Names["System`*"]},
 OptionsDictionary[HoldPattern[optionList_ : Sequence[]], 
   symbolList_List : symbolListDefault] :=
  
  With[{optionsForSymbols = 
     Quiet@ReleaseHold@
       Thread@Hold[Options][symbolList, Hold@optionList]},
   Transpose@
      {symbolList[[#]] /. HoldComplete -> HoldForm, 
       RulesToOptionList@optionsForSymbols[[#]], 
       SetOptionsQ@symbolList[[#]]} &@
    Flatten@Position[optionsForSymbols, {__}, {1}]
   ]
 ]
```

Usage:

```
OptionsDictionary[{ContentPadding, ImageSize}] // Grid
OptionsDictionary[GeneratedCellStyles] // Grid
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

As a bonus (off-topic a bit), here are a couple helper utilities that I found useful in visualizing the data structure while I was developing this:

```
LevelFormatted = Function[{expr, level, patternTest}, {
    level,
    Row@Map[
       Framed[patternTest@First@#, 
         Background -> If[level == 0, None, Last@#]] &]@
      MapIndexed[{#1, GrayLevel[.3, 0.2 - 0.1*Mod[First@#2, 2]]} &]@
       Level[expr, {level}]
    },
   Listable
   ];

LevelGrid = Function[{expr, patternTest},
   Grid[#, Frame -> All, Background -> {
        {1 -> LightYellow},
        {{{LightBlue, None}}, Depth[expr] + 3 -> LightYellow}
        }] &@
    Prepend[{Style[ToString@Unevaluated@expr, Bold], SpanFromLeft}]@
     LevelFormatted[Unevaluated@expr, 
      Range[-Depth[expr] - 1, Depth[expr]], patternTest],
   HoldAllComplete
   ];

RuleLevels = 
  Function[expr, 
   LevelGrid[expr, Row@{Framed@#, Framed@FreeQ[_Rule]@#} &], HoldAll];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is another problem caused by the [significant change of graphics functionality between versions 5 and 6](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#8551). (As to other problems, check [post about `AbsoluteOptions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68937/1871) and [post about `FullGraphics`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83648/1871).)

A key evidence is `Text`. As [mentioned by Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/332/how-can-i-work-out-which-functions-work-with-setoptions#comment89652_1073), this is a function that doesn't call those functions mentioned in [Mike's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1073/1871), yet `SetOptions` still fails on it, for example:

```
$Version

SetOptions[Text, Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]];
Text["A", {0, 0}] // Graphics
```

[image]

But it's not the case in *v5*:

[image]

BTW, you may think you can reproduce the old behavior with

```
<<Version5`Graphics`
```

but unfortunately it's buggy in this case:

[image]

So, functions related to graphics added or modified in or after *v6* are likely to be influenced, but I can't think out a systematic way to test my guess at the moment.