# Why does ListPlot ignore some global options?

Tags: plotting, bugs, options

**Bug introduced in 7.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 8.0.1**'

---

Why does the following plot no use the global `PlotMarkers` option?

```
SetOptions[ListPlot, {ImageSize -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> {"A"}}];
ListPlot[Range[10]]
```

Checking the global options for `ListPlot` shows that `PlotMarkers` is set on a global level:

```
Options[ListPlot, {PlotMarkers}] -> {PlotMarkers -> {"A"}}
```

If I just feed the `ListPlot` function all of it global options it plots correctly, but it defeats the purpose of having globally set defaults.

```
ListPlot[Range[10], Options[ListPlot]]
```

To my knowledge `ListPlot[Range[10]]` and `ListPlot[Range[10], Options[ListPlot]]` should always return the same result but in this case it does not.

I'm running Mathematica 8.0.0.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: I don't have an authorative answer, but I have expressed my opinion on global options in this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/332/how-can-i-work-out-which-functions-work-with-setoptions/385#385, which may be somewhat relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In version 7 it appears that `ListPlot` only uses global `Options[]` that are acceptable to `Graphics` (probably via `FilterRules`).  You can work around this manually with explicit declaration:

```
SetOptions[ListPlot, {PlotMarkers -> {"A"}, Filling -> Axis}];

ListPlot[Range[10], Options[ListPlot]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to make this fix automatic you can do this:

```
Unprotect[ListPlot];

ListPlot[args___] :=
  Block[{$lpOptsFix = True},
    ListPlot[args, Options[ListPlot]]
  ] /; ! TrueQ[$lpOptsFix]
```

Comment: Your last suggestion is pretty much going down the same road as I did when constructing the option configuratin manager which I linked to in the comment above.

Comment: I never meant any opposition. Just made a note to link things, because I think there is more value when related discussions or techniques presented in various places are linked together. Totally agree on complementarity.

Comment: Thank I was looking for something like  you ListPlot rewrite.

Comment: @Davorak, glad I could help, and thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like a bug that has been fixed for V8.0.1.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the fix.

Comment: @Brett Champion I just ran into the same problem (I think) in 8.0.4