# Annoyance: Plot Markers disappear when ListPlot options are set in SetOptions instead of in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does ListPlot ignore some global options?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/why-does-listplot-ignore-some-global-options)

Using this data:

```
curve = {{0.833, 0.1}, {0.25, 0.08}, {0.5, 0.15}, {1, 0.2}, {2, 
0.3}, {3, 0.45}, {5, 0.75}, {7, 1.25}, {10, 1.85}, {20, 
2.55}, {30, 3}};
```

ListPlot with options set inside show plot markers:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But if I put the exact same options in SetOptions, like this:

```
SetOptions[ListPlot, ImageSize->300, Frame->True, Joined->True, PlotMarkers->Automatic,
AxesOrigin->{0.5,0}, PlotRange->All, GridLines->Automatic, GridLinesStyle->LightGray,
FrameLabel->{"Years","Yield (%)","Treasury Yield Curve on Oct 17, 2012"},
LabelStyle->{11, FontFamily -> "Arial"}];
```

The plot markers disappear.  I perfer to keep the (relatively unimportant) options out of posts here, showing only the data, plot function, and results.  This annoyance thwarts me.

Comment: It seems to work with `ListLinePlot` and corresponding options (minus the `Joined` part).

Comment: I guess that would do the trick for my purpose, and I'll use it. But it should work with ListPlot.

Comment: I agree, hopefully you'll get a better answer.

Comment: Looks buggy, right? Seems when neither `PlotRange` or `AxesOrigin` aren't in `Automatic` it forgets to check `PlotMarkers` in the defaults? Blergh

Comment: This kind of thing has come up before.  I expect to close this question as a duplicate soon, but for now I believe the standard work-around is `ListPlot[curve, Options@ListPlot]`

Comment: Yeah, alternatively, you could set the `PlotRange` or `AxesOrigin` options in some creepy way like `DisplayFunction -> ($DisplayFunction@Show[#, AxesOrigin -> {0.5, 0}, DisplayFunction -> Identity] &)` and leave the "real" option as `Automatic`