# Options problem for 3D plots

Tags: graphics3d, mesh

If I'm not mistaken, the code below *should* produce two identical pictures of a torus.  But it does not.  The MeshStyle->Thick option seems to be ignored for the first.  Obviously the second code provides a workaround - but is this a bug, or do I not know how "SetOptions" works?

```
SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D,
    Axes->False,
    Boxed->False,
    Mesh->20,
    PlotStyle->Glow[White],
    MeshStyle->Thick
    ]


g1 =    ParametricPlot3D[
    {Cos[u]*(Sqrt[2]+Cos[t]), Sin[u]*(Sqrt[2]+Cos[t]),Sin[t]
    }, {u,0,2Pi},{t,0,2Pi}]

g2 =    ParametricPlot3D[
    {Cos[u]*(Sqrt[2]+Cos[t]), Sin[u]*(Sqrt[2]+Cos[t]),Sin[t]
    }, {u,0,2Pi},{t,0,2Pi},
    MeshStyle->Thick
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: related: [Why does ListPlot ignore some global options?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1268/125), [GridLinesStyle not working with SetOptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160598/125), [How can I work out which functions work with SetOptions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/332/125)

Comment: a workaround: `Block[{parametricPlot3D = ParametricPlot3D}, 
 SetOptions[parametricPlot3D, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
  Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Glow[White], MeshStyle -> Thick];
 parametricPlot3D[{Cos[u]*(Sqrt[2] + Cos[t]), 
   Sin[u]*(Sqrt[2] + Cos[t]), Sin[t]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]`