# Problems with setting style options

Tags: stylesheet, options

Consider the following:

```
FirstOutput=Style["Test", FontSize -> 20]

SetOptions[Style, FontSize -> 20];
SecondOutput=Style["Test"]
```

I would like the string `"Test"` to appear in `SecondOutput` as in `FirstOutput`. Why does `SetOptions[Style, FontSize -> 20]` not apply to `SecondOutput`?

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some functions that don't work with `SetOptions`. [This Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/332/how-can-i-work-out-which-functions-work-with-setoptions) provides a WRI tech support solution to finding functions that don't work with `SetOptions` but it appears that that method doesn't pick up `Style` (or `StyleBox`).

Answer (score 2):

I think Mike Honeychurch has the gist of it. I don't know why Style doesn't use it's option values, but if you test it out, get display problems if you call

```
Style["test", Sequence @@ Options[Style]]
```

send the message:

> The specified setting for the option OpenerBoxOptions, BaselinePosition cannot be used.

If you want something similar I suggest you simply define your own style call, which for the most case also nicely documents that you don't just want to call an empty `Style[]` on a piece of text, but want it to follow some personally defined styling.

```
Options[myStyle]={FontSize->20};
myStyle[a__,OptionsPattern[]]:=Style[a,Sequence@@Options[myStyle]]
```

I would personally expect `Style["text"]` to be the default style, which means that the call is redundant, since `"text"` in and of itself would have the default style.