# GridLinesStyle not working with SetOptions

Tags: plotting, options, plot-themes, grid-lines

On all the plots of a notebook I have to put a vertical line at the same place. I thus use the GridLines option for Plot along with the option GridLinesStyle. To get it done easily I use the function SetOption for Plot:

```
SetOptions[Plot,GridLines->{{1},{}},GridLinesStyle->Red]
Plot[x,{x, 0, 2}]
Plot[x,{x, 0, 2},GridLinesStyle->Red]
```

[image]

The style has not been applied to the GridLine in the first plot

[image]

It worked here

Am I doing something wrong, or is it just that GridLinesStyle does not work with SetOptions for some reason? I do apologize if this question has already been asked but I could not find any information about this issue.

Comment: In the second plot `GridLinesStyle` overrides previous settings . What I am also wondering why the first case does not work... However, it works with `PlotStyle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain options can be overwritten by `PlotTheme` so we can skip it:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, PlotTheme -> None]
```

[image]

Would be nice to have more official/documented investigation tools but meanwhile you can search around to learn more:

- [Specifying non-conflicting PlotTheme options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51846/5478)

And here's something related:

- [How can I work out which functions work with SetOptions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/332/5478)

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bug, might be worth reporting it. But here is a work around. Assign the output of `SetOptions` to global variable, and then use that in all your plots. If you want to add options locally, you can append to them. Like this

```
globalPlotOptions=SetOptions[Plot,GridLines->{{1},{}},GridLinesStyle->Red];
p=Plot[x,{x,0,2},Evaluate@globalPlotOptions]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to add options for some plot then make sure to put those local options *before* adding the global ones

```
globalPlotOptions=SetOptions[Plot,GridLines->{{1},{}},GridLinesStyle->Red];
p=Plot[x,{x,0,2},PlotStyle->Dashed,Evaluate@globalPlotOptions]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

i.e do not do this below, as it will have no effect:

```
globalPlotOptions=SetOptions[Plot,GridLines->{{1},{}},GridLinesStyle->Red];
p=Plot[x,{x,0,2},Evaluate@globalPlotOptions,PlotStyle->Dashed]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since order makes difference.  This means you just have to add `Evaluate@globalPlotOptions` each time to all the plot commands. This is work around until one find why this option is not making any effect or if it is a bug, until it is fixed.